# Map a canvas Texture to a plane

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that has been drawn on, that I want to map to a plane in 3D space. For some reason, all I see is a green rectangle.

I have the canvas next to the webgl renderer, and I do know that the canvas is draw on before the texture is created.

```
this.geom = new THREE.Geometry();//, side:THREE.DoubleSide
    this.tex = new THREE.Texture(canvas2d);
    //this.tex.needsUpdate = false;
    //color: 0x0033ff,
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:this.tex, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
    for(var i = 0; i < this.array.length;i++) {
        this.geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(this.array[i].x, 0, this.array[i].y));
        this.geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(this.array[i].x, this.h3d , this.array[i].y));
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < this.geom.vertices.length-3; i++) {
        this.geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i+0,i+2,i+1));
        this.geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i+2,i+3,i+1));
    }
    this.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( this.geom, this.material );
    scene.add( cube );
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you're not providing any texture mapping. e.g., this.geom.faceVertexUvs. This could be the cause of the problem.